# CoreData Parent Child Context Conflict Management

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, parent-child, nsmanagedobjectcontext

**Core data application, that Syncs user data from `CloudKit`.**

We have two core data context

1. Main Context :- UI (Insert, Update, Delete from User )
2. Child Context :- That fetches changes from cloud kit and once done
   saves the changes to Main Context.

**Problems**:

Since its a parent-child setup the changes from parent do not get reflected in child. So while the child is syncing changes to `CloudKit` if the parent context get updated, then child is not aware of that changes.

Say child context is trying to upload a record A to `CloudKit` meanwhile if user modifies the same record as below

- User updates :- the new updates are lost when child saves the record 
  to parent.
- User Deletes :- (we just mark it as deleted) the child re-saves the child since it do not get the property marked as deleted.

  **Question**:

  1. Can child somehow know of the parent updates?
     Can i refresh the object before i save?
  2. In Parent-Child Setup does child always overrides parent changes without getting merge conflicts?

Answer (score 2):

1. Set the context's automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent property.
2. Choose an appropriate merge policy.

FYI Parent/Child contexts are not for this they are for create/update screens, where changes made by the user can be cancelled and discarded leaving the main context alone. For network sync you should be using a background context associated with the persistent store. See `NSPersistentContainer` `newBackgroundContext`.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at this tutorial it may help.

[Multiple Context swift tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113489/core-data-tutorial-multiple-managed-object-contexts)

Comment: its just the overview of concept. It does not help in my case.

Comment: If you have an answer to the question you should explain it explicitly;  you can also link to the source. Just posting a link is not an answer.

Comment: I used refresh object thing, but then also am still facing issues while saving child